# how to align multi level rcases in latex math

Tags: math-mode, align, cases

I'm trying to get an equation aligned with multiple levels of rcases:

[image: multi level rcases]

But at least one of them doesn't align.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use nested `array` environments, and I would make the second right-hand curly brace span *all three* columns to its left.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
\left.\begin{array}{r@{}r@{}}
    \left.\begin{array}{r@{}}
       a<b \\
       b\le c
    \end{array}\right\}
 & {}\Rightarrow a<c\\
 & c<d
\end{array}\right\}
\Rightarrow a<d
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: In order to achieve a look that's close to the screenshot you posted, it is necessary to add a third nesting level of `array`s and to rearrange some of the terms relative to the solution shown above. The new solution has top-level `array` with 3 columns, each one consisting of a mid-level `array`. The first (left-hand) mid-level `array` contains a bottom-level `array` that spans rows 1-3 (with row 2 blank) and an associated right-hand curly brace, plus a blank row. The second mid-level `array` contains a blank row followed by a bottom-level `array` that spans rows 2-4 (with row 3 blank) and an associated right-hand curly brace. The third (right-hand) mid-level `array` contains just 1 non-blank row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{rrr} % outermost ("top-level") array
  \begin{array}{c} % first mid-level array
    \left.\begin{array}{c}
       a<b \\ \\ b\le c
    \end{array}\right\} \\
    \\ % end with a blank row
  \end{array} &
  \begin{array}{c} % second mid-level array
    \\ % start with a blank row
    \left.\begin{array}{r}
       {}\Rightarrow  a<c \\ \\ c<d
    \end{array}\right\}
  \end{array} &
  \begin{array}{c} % third and final mid-level array
   \\ \\ {}\Rightarrow a<d \\ \\
  \end{array}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, but is there any way to just span two rows in the right-hand brace? I mean, it is not a bit wider than what I needed (the extra space above _a<c_)

Comment: @Farzad - I've posted an addendum to show a solution that replicates your original screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution, with `rcases` and `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{rcases}
  a<b \\
  b \le c
  \end{rcases}
  {} \Rightarrow \begin{aligned}[t]\\[-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax] \begin{rcases}
    a<c\\
    c<d
    \end{rcases}
    %
     \Rightarrow a<d
    \end{aligned}
  \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For information, `\fontdimen22`is the distance of the mathaxis to the base line, and `textfont2` denotes the mathsymbols font, which are centred on the math axis.

Comment: @Mico: Done! One never checks enough details. Note I'm not really a TeXpert…